# Finding origin of a file in a network drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have around 6 Windows systems in my office connected with the server. We have a network drive when we drop all the files we want to share. My problem is how to find who dropped what file.

Comment: Isn't this what source control is for? Sharepoint does this I think!

Comment: I don't have any idea about source control. We have just shared a drive in network

Answer (score 0):

If you know that what to track what is going on, you need to enable File auditing, and logging of both success and fail file audit actions.  You might want to look at enabling that.  How you do that depends on the server.

If you don't have auditing enabled, and you are looking at this after the fact you may not be able to tell at all.

If the server is Windows based and the filesystem is NTFS, then you could try right clicking on the file, hitting the security tab, then looking to see who owns the file.